# Compare value in combo box with value in hidden field

Tags: javascript, telerik

I have several telerik radComboboxes and each has a corresponding hidden field.
The combos have an id prefix of cmb and their hidden field have a prefix of hd. I used these to detect if any combo box has had its value changed or if I need to reset the combo back to its initial value. I have the following JavaScript which is fired onClienSelectedIndexChanged...

```
function cmbSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {

            var selectedItem = eventArgs.get_item();

            var selectedItemText = selectedItem != null ? selectedItem.get_text() : sender.get_text();

            var hd = sender.attr('id').replace("cmb", "hd");

            if (selectedItemText !== $('#' + hd).val()) {

                registerChange();

            }

        }
```

I get an error - **object doesn't this property or method** - on the line beginning **var hd**

What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: if your passing object try var hd = $(sender).attr('id').replace("cmb", "hd"); if you're passing id use var hd = $('#'+sender).attr('id').replace("cmb", "hd");

Comment: Thanks rakhee... They are objects so I tried $(sender) and now get a JavaScript runtime error 'attr(...)' is null or not an object on the same line. If I try your other suggestion I get a js runtime syntax error unrecognised expression: #[object Object]

Comment: well, means your passing elements object not need to try second one...!

Comment: I was fairly sure that I was passing object but I just tried the code $('#' + sender) just in case.... So why am I getting null or not object error... Any ideas?

Comment: check whether your hidden element id is same as your variable hd value....!

Comment: Yes they are the same... cmb_Status and hd_Status as example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32496/discussion-between-rakhee-and-mych)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be searching for the ClientId of the control therefore the code will not work. Instead of

`var hd = sender.attr('id').replace("cmb", "hd");`

You should try something along the lines of:

`var hd = sender.get_id().replace("cmb", "hd").replace(/_/,"$");`

The above code will convert the client id of the telerik combo box into the "name" attribute of the element of the asp hidden control. I believe the code below should resolve the problem described (I apologize for the extra comments I was using this as a teaching aid earlier and thought it might be beneficial to other users)

```
function cmbSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
    // Get Selected Item
    var selectedItem = eventArgs.get_item();
    // Get Selected Text
    var selectedItemText = selectedItem != null ? selectedItem.get_text() : sender.get_text();
    // Convert Telerik element id to Asp Control name
    var hd = sender.get_id().replace("cmb", "hd").replace(/_/g,"$");
    // Compare the asp:HiddenField value to the selected text
    if (selectedItemText !== document.getElementsByName( hd)[0].value) {
        registerChange();
    }
}
```

When debugging this locally I didn't have JQuery registered on the page so my updated function uses the .getElementsByName function instead of the JQuery equivalent  e.g. `$('[name="' + hd + '"]')`.